# Importing Gesture search resource into my application

Tags: java, android, gesture, gestures

Hi I have been making an app that recognizes gestures. I am attempting to use Google's gesture search resource file in my program.

**The problem**: The gesture resource file crashes my application and also gesture builder (on emulator)

**My question**: How does Google (and in turn how would I) load the gesture resource file without crashing out of memory errors?

Error log below:

```
03-01 13:02:55.406: E/dalvikvm-heap(32207): Out of memory on a 13893864-byte allocation.
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:75)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.gesture.GestureStroke.deserialize(GestureStroke.java:223)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.gesture.Gesture.deserialize(Gesture.java:277)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.gesture.GestureStore.readFormatV1(GestureStore.java:322)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.gesture.GestureStore.load(GestureStore.java:293)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.gesture.GestureLibraries$ResourceGestureLibrary.load(GestureLibraries.java:132)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at com.example.transittalker.main.onCreate(main.java:99)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2136)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2207)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
03-01 13:02:55.416: E/AndroidRuntime(32207):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gesture libraries are supposed to be fairly small files. I have a file with about 8-10 gestures, and it's only 6KB. Did you generate this file using the Gesture Builder, and if so, did you remove any extraneous gestures (especially from testing & construction)?

If not, the gestures resource file could certainly grow quite large and perhaps become corrupted.

If possible, I would suggest deleting the gestures resource file from the emulator that you're running the Gesture Builder on, and starting over with a clean file generated by the Builder. Try testing your code with only one or two gestures, then add more.

Edit: Just checking, but your gestures file should not have an extension, it should be in the /res/raw directory, and it's a binary file, if that might have made a difference when you copied/transferred it.

Comment: 1. File is 250kb. 2.I have an xml with a similar size which runs fine. 3. I do not know if the gesture file is corrupt. I am unable to open it in gesture builder without crashing.

Comment: on average 5 for every letter in english and numbers as well.

Comment: You're probably going to have to break that up into smaller chunks of symbols.